# jQuery - Updating Button Icon after database access fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I feel like the solution to this should be really simple, but I cannot for the life of me figure it out. Here's the setup:

I have a database with some alarm clock times saved. On my website, there is a button with the id #addTimeBtn which allows the user to enter a date, time, and song choice for an alarm. A script (included below) handles the click by adding the information the user has just entered into a div with the id #alarmTimeList. In the same script, I have a function that is called every 60 seconds to query the database via a php script. This function gets the dates, times, and song choices from the database and adds them to #alarmTimeList.

Here's the problem: Both #addTimeBtn and reloadAlarmTimes() create identical code in the #alarmTimeList div. However, when the relaoadAlarmTimes() function is called, the button identified by class .deleteBtn is not passed through the jQuery functions to create the button. Upon inspection via Chrome's developer tools, the div for the button has been created, it just hasn't been passed through the jQuery UI stuff to make it snazzy. The code to create the button is identical in both the #addTimeBtn click handling and the reloadAlarmTimes() function, but only the first works. Thoughts?

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Make the date picker a jQuery datepicker object
    $("#dateInput").datepicker();

    //Set up the addTimeBtn
    $("#addTimeBtn")
        .button({icons: {primary: "ui-icon-plus", secondary: null} })
        .on('click', function() {
            //Get the inputs
            var date = $("input[id=dateInput]").val();
            var time = $("input[id=timeInput]").val();
            var song = $("#songInput").val();

            //Create list item code
            var alarmTimeCode = "<div class='listItem'>";
            alarmTimeCode += "<div class='date'>"+date+"</div>";
            alarmTimeCode += "<div class='time'>"+time+"</div>";
            alarmTimeCode += "<div class='song'>"+song+"</div>";
            alarmTimeCode += "<div class='deleteBtn'></div>";
            alarmTimeCode += "</div>";

            //Add the code to the window
            $(alarmTimeCode).appendTo("#alarmTimeList");

            //Set up the delete button
            $(".deleteBtn")
                .button({icons: {primary: "ui-icon-minus", secondary: null}})
                .on('click', function(){
                    $(this).parent("div").remove();
                });

            //Clean up
            $("input[id=dateInput]").val('');
            $("input[id=timeInput]").val('');
        });


    //Run the reloadAlarmTimes() function every 60 seconds
    reloadAlarmTimes();

    setInterval(reloadAlarmTimes, 60000);

});

function reloadAlarmTimes(){
    //Connect to DB, get data, load into AlarmTimeList
    $("#alarmTimeList").load("/scripts/getAllAlarmTimes.php");

    //Set up the delete button
    $(".deleteBtn")
        .button({icons: {primary: "ui-icon-minus", secondary: null}})
        .on('click', function(){
            $(this).parent("div").remove();
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought would be to use the callback function that you can pass to load. I believe this is an asynchronous call and your code to button-ify the elment is likely running before the response has returned or before the response is added to the DOM.

```
function reloadAlarmTimes(){
  //Connect to DB, get data, load into AlarmTimeList
  $("#alarmTimeList").load("/scripts/getAllAlarmTimes.php", function() {

      //Set up the delete button
      $(".deleteBtn")
        .button({icons: {primary: "ui-icon-minus", secondary: null}})
        .on('click', function(){
          $(this).parent("div").remove();
       });

  });
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: That was indeed the problem! The PHP query to the database must have taken long enough that the buttons hadn't been created until after the jQuery button-ify code had been run.